# How do you find all matches in regexes with C?

Tags: c, regex, posix

Is there a findall function in C's regex library like there is in python:

```
re.findall(pattern, input_string)
```

I have a string containing filenames like so: `"path/to/file1.ics,path/file2.ics"` with an **undetermined** number of files in the string. I want to find all the filenames (including their path) and put them in an array of strings.

I'm using the GNU `regex.h` library

Comment: Are they all comma-separated?  Perhaps you can use the built-in `strtok` function and bypass regexes entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using POSIX `regcomp`/`regexec`, each call to `regexec` will only find the *first* match in the string. To find the next, use the end position of the first match (the 0th entry of the `regmatch_t` array filled by `regexec`) as an offset to apply to the string before searching it again. Repeat until you have no more matches. You can write a function to do this if you want.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard library (as specified by ISO/IEC 9899) does not include a regular expression module, so you will need to use an external library.  Good choices include [regex.h from GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html), as detailed in [/questions/635756](//stackoverflow.com/questions/635756/) and [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), as detailed in [/questions/1421785](//stackoverflow.com/questions/1421785/).

Comment: I am using that library, sorry, forgot to mention that in the OP.

Comment: Which library?  GNU libc or PCRE?

Comment: Whichever library it is that you're using, go back and edit your question and put that bit of information in the question.

Comment: Using GNU, added to OP